# IBM MQ Asynchronous fetch using .Net

Tags: .net, asynchronous, ibm-mq, mq

I have created a windows service using MQI is there a way to add asynchronous fetch to MQGet i have tried it using Message Listener.But what to do it using MQConn without threading Please find the below code

```
         while (queueGetMessageOptions.GroupStatus != QC.MQGS_LAST_MSG_IN_GROUP)
        {
            try
            {                   
                inboundmsg = new MQMessage();                  
                queuerecieve.Get(inboundmsg, queueGetMessageOptions);
            }
       }
```

Is the above code correct. Do i need to set the Group Status? Because the service should be running and listening to the queue continously

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question and code don't match.  Is the sender putting messages messages in groups?  Because your code is looking for exactly 1 group of messages then it exits the loop.

If you want to read all messages (no group) in a loop then you should do something like:

```
MQMessage           mqMsg;
MQGetMessageOptions gmo = new MQGetMessageOptions();
gmo.WaitInterval = 15000;  // wait for up to 15 seconds
gmo.Options |= MQC.MQGMO_WAIT;

bool isContinue = true;
while (isContinue)
{
   mqMsg = new MQMessage();
   try
   {
      mqQueue.Get( mqMsg, gmo );
      if (mqMsg.Format.CompareTo(MQC.MQFMT_STRING) == 0)
      {
         System.Console.WriteLine(  mqMsg.ReadString(mqMsg.MessageLength) );
      }
      else
      {
         System.Console.WriteLine( "Non-text message" );
      }
   }
   catch (MQException mqe)
   {
      // report reason, if any
      if ( mqe.Reason == MQC.MQRC_NO_MSG_AVAILABLE )
      {
         System.Console.WriteLine( "no more messages - go loop again" );
      }
      else
      {
         System.Console.WriteLine( "MQQueue::Get ended with " + mqe.Message );

         isContinue = false;
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Yes.  I prefer to have each thread make their own connection to the queue manager.

Comment: Can i give the wait interval as gmo.WaitInterval = MQC.MQWI_UNLIMITED; because when I set the Wait interval to 15000; After I Stop the service the code is being executed one and i get an exception Exception while recieving the messagesSystem.Threading.ThreadAbortException: Thread was being aborted.
       at IBM.WMQ.MQDestination.Get(MQMessage message, MQGetMessageOptions gmo, Int32 maxMsgSize)

Comment: When MQ is in the middle of a Get then thread is locked. It is a bad idea to use MQC.MQWI_UNLIMITED for a service. I generally use a wait of 2 seconds for a service that way the code can check if the service has been stopped and then GRACEFULLY close the queue & disconnect from the queue manager.   Also, did you add code to handle setting the flag to false when the service is stopped?